# Error when using JURI::current(); in facebook like in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a example:
When I enter link url(ex: http://test.html) And like facebook in this page

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:like send="true" layout="button_count" width="50" show_faces="false" href="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" action="like" colorscheme="light" font=""></fb:like>
```

But when i access facebook is url is:

```
http://test.html?fb_action_ids=214927585304828&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582
```

How to fix it, result is `http://test.html`

Comment: @Justion Wood: Problem when access facebook is link url not right is test.html, but it is test.html?fb_action....

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` That may give what you're looking for...

Cheers.